# Variance Inflation Factor for 2 categorical variables is coming to be greater than 5, can I drop one of them?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, supervised-learning, variance-inflation-factor

I am practicing Linear Regression on the Airbnb dataset. The VIF for 2 dummy variables 'room_type_Entire home/apt' and 'room_type_Private room' is coming as '9.546159' and '9.116464'. These dummy variables I got after applying OHE and dummy encoding on the categorical variable 'room_type' which had 3 categories initially.  Can I drop one of the dummy variables say 'room_type_Entire home/apt'? In general if we have k dummy variables out of which j(j<k) are having VIF > 5 can we drop j-1 dummy variables?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why drop *any* of the variables?

Comment: I am dropping 'room_type_Entire home/apt' because I want to handle multicollinearity in the design matrix. There seem to a linear dependence b/w  the 'room_type_Entire home/apt' and the 'room_type_Private room'. Based on the value for VIF being greater than 5 I came to this decision.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to drop an entire factor or just one level after you one-hot encode a categorical variable?

Comment: Of course you can drop any variables you like.  But basing your decision solely on VIF is unwise and often will result in a poor regression.  You need to examine the correlation structure in greater detail than that and you need to consider more clearly *why* you are performing this regression.  Can you explain your objectives?

Comment: I want to determine the 'price' based on the features. These are the features I got after the data pre-processing step: 
accommodates(float) bathrooms(float) cleaning_fee(0 for True 1 for False) instant_bookable(0 for True 1 for False) review_scores_rating(float) bedrooms(float) beds(float) room_type_Entire home/apt(dummy_variable) room_type_Private room (dummy_variable) cancellation_policy_flexible(dummy_variable) cancellation_policy_moderate(dummy_variable). Also, the correlation co-efficient b/w the 'room_type_Entire home/apt' and 'room_type_Private room' is coming as -0.94.

Comment: I also have doubt if it is correct and meaningful to take consider the correlation coefficient b/w these two dummy variables.

Comment: @Dave, I want to drop just one level after I did one-hot encoding and dummy variable encoding based on the multicollinearity check.

Comment: Since your purpose is prediction, you shouldn't care much, if at all, about those VIFs.

Comment: @Whuber, I too feel that the dummy variables 'room_type_Private room' and 'room_type_Entire home/apt' are important for predicting the 'price', and dropping one of them results in loss of information as per what 'room_type' has been selected.

Comment: When I use the the OLS class from statsmodels.regression.linear_model for calculating the regression coefficients the p-values for these 2 dummy variables was coming to less than 0.05 whereas for the 'cancellation_policy_flexible' it was .732 so I dropped the 'cancellation_policy_flexible' variable. Although even after dropping the 'cancellation_policy_flexible' variable when I again build the linear regression model there was not much difference in accuracy(R2-score).

Comment: p-values are not very relevant for you when your sole objective is prediction.